# Responsive text positioning?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive, bootstrap-carousel

I use Bootstrap carousel slider with text (carousel-caption). It is responsive on all device, but the text is always centered and on the bottom of screen. I know how to position the text wherever I want.

But if I change the position, it isn't properly displayed on other devices. I just want to position the text to the left and in the middle of the screen and I want it to stay there when I resize the viewport.

```css
.carousel-caption {
  top: 35%;
  width:500px;
  left: 220px;
  bottom: auto;
}

.red {
  color:red;
  
}

.carousel-item {
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 350px;
  background: no-repeat center center scroll;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.lnr {
  display: inline-block;
  fill: currentColor;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  vertical-align: -0.05em;
  stroke-width: 1;
}

.services-icon {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
bgc2, .vLine, .hLine {
    background-color: #0F52BA;
}

.quote-icon {
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.services-icon {
    font-size: 60px;
    margin-left: 2rem;
}

    .slide1-title {
      font-size: 40px;
    } 
    
    .slide1-content{
      font-size:18px;
    }   
.btn-style-one {
  position: relative;
  padding: 14px 30px;
  line-height: 1em;
  background: #221f1f;
  margin-top: 20px;
  color: #ffffff !important;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid transparent !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>                        
                </ol>
          <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <!-- Slide One - Set the background image for this slide in the line below -->
            <div class="carousel-item active" style="background-image: url('https://images.wallpaperscraft.com/image/windows_7_black_glass_reflection_26309_1920x1080.jpg')">
              <div class="carousel-caption d-lg-block slide1-bg">
                
                    <h2 class="display-4  slide1-title" style="text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: bold;"></h2><br>
                <p class="lead slide1 slide1-content"><i>TEXT for position</i><br>
                    <a href="#o-nama" class="theme-btn btn-style-one scroll-to-target" data-target="#o-nama">BUTTON</a>
                
              </div>
            </div>
            
               </div>
            </div>        
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-arrow">
          <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
              </a>
          <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
              </a>
            </div>
        </div>
                      
          </div>
```

Comment: Please share your  code

Comment: 2 Questions: Where is your code that you tried so far? Which bootstrap are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For minimal change; replace your '.carousel-caption' style block with the below:

```
.carousel-caption {
  top: 0 !important;
  left: 0 !important;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100vw;
  padding: 0 15%;
}
```

And add for that "I just want to put text left in the middle of the screen":

```
.carousel-caption .lead {
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  top: 45vh;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c3h0zt9b/

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you want to center the text horizontally or vertically. So both answers:
**Horizontally**
The element you want to center `.carousel-caption` has a px width and margins in percentage.

You can either use percentage values only:

```
.carousel-caption {
    width: 70%;
    left: 15%;
}
```

or just make it full width, as all the contained text is centered:

```
.carousel-caption {
   width: 100%;
   left: 0px;
   right:0px;
}
```

**Vertically**

```
.carousel-caption {
    top: 50%;
    bottom: auto;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.carousel-item .carousel-caption {
  top: 35%;
  width:500px;
  left: 220px;
  bottom: auto;
right: auto;
text-align: left;
}

.red {
  color:red;
  
}

.carousel-item {
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 350px;
  background: no-repeat center center scroll;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.lnr {
  display: inline-block;
  fill: currentColor;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  vertical-align: -0.05em;
  stroke-width: 1;
}

.services-icon {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
bgc2, .vLine, .hLine {
    background-color: #0F52BA;
}

.quote-icon {
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.services-icon {
    font-size: 60px;
    margin-left: 2rem;
}

    .slide1-title {
      font-size: 40px;
    } 
    
    .slide1-content{
      font-size:18px;
    }   
.btn-style-one {
  position: relative;
  padding: 14px 30px;
  line-height: 1em;
  background: #221f1f;
  margin-top: 20px;
  color: #ffffff !important;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid transparent !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>                        
                </ol>
          <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <!-- Slide One - Set the background image for this slide in the line below -->
            <div class="carousel-item active" style="background-image: url('https://images.wallpaperscraft.com/image/windows_7_black_glass_reflection_26309_1920x1080.jpg')">
              <div class="carousel-caption d-lg-block slide1-bg">
                
                    <h2 class="display-4  slide1-title" style="text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: bold;"></h2><br>
                <p class="lead slide1 slide1-content"><i>TEXT for position</i><br>
                    <a href="#o-nama" class="theme-btn btn-style-one scroll-to-target" data-target="#o-nama">BUTTON</a>
                
              </div>
            </div>
            
               </div>
            </div>        
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-arrow">
          <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
              </a>
          <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
              </a>
            </div>
        </div>
                      
          </div>
```